# how to make el-select and v-model work together when extracting a custom component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

I'm using [el-select](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select) to build a select component. Something like this:

```
<template>
    //omitted code
    <el-select v-model="filterForm.client"
                    filterable
                    remote
                    placeholder="Please enter a keyword"
                    :remote-method="filterClients"
                    :loading="loading">
                <el-option
                        v-for="item in clientCandidates"
                        :key="item._id"
                        :label="item.name"
                        :value="item._id">
                </el-option>
            </el-select>
</template>
<scripts>
    export default {
        data() {
           filterForm: {
                client: ''
           },
           clientCandidates: [],
           loading: false
        },
        methods: {
            filterClients(query) {
                if (query !== '') {
                    this.loading = true;
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.clientCandidates = [{_id: '1', name: 'foo'}, {_id: '2', name: 'bar'}];
                    }, 200);
                } else {
                    this.clientCandidates = [];
                }
            }
        }
    }
</scripts>
```

So far so good, but since the component will appear in different pages, so I want to extract a custom component to avoid duplication.

According to the [guideline](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components),

```
v-model="fullName"
```

is equivalent to

```
v-bind:value="fullName"
v-on:input="$emit('input', $event)"
```

So I extracted the select component like this:

```
<template>
<el-select
        v-bind:value="clientId"
        v-on:input="$emit('input', $event)"
        placeholder="Filter by short name"
        filterable="true"
        remote="true"
        :remote-method="filter"
        :loading="loading">
    <el-option
            v-for="item in clients"
            :key="item._id"
            :label="item.name"
            :value="item._id">
    </el-option>
</el-select>
</template>
<scripts>
export default {
    props: {
        clientId: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            clients: [],
            loading: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        filter(query) {
            if (query !== '') {
                this.loading = true;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.clients = [{_id: '1', name: 'foo'}, {_id: '2', name: 'bar'}];
                }, 200);
            } else {
                this.clients = [];
            }
        }
    }
}
</scripts>
```

And the parent component looks like this:

```
<select-client v-model="filterForm.clientId"></select-client>
```

The select drop down works fine, but unfortunately, the select does not reveal the option I selected, it remains empty after I choose an option. I suspect that maybe I should switch the `v-on:input` to 'v-on:change', but it does not work either.

**UPDATE**
I created a simple example, you can clone it [here](https://github.com/Hippoom/element-ui-questions/tree/el-select-as-component), please checkout the `el-select-as-component` branch. Run

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

You will see a simple page with 3 kinds of select:
The left one is a custom component written in raw select, it works fine.
The middle one is a custom component written in `el-select`, the dropdown remains empty but you can see the `filterForm.elClientId` in the console once you click `Filter` button. This is why I raise this question.
The right one is a plain `el-select`, it works fine.

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pls ?

Comment: @JacobGoh thank you, I've updated the question with a github sample.

Comment: I forked your repo and make you a PR when I finish

Comment: PR here > https://github.com/Hippoom/element-ui-questions/pull/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guideline says `v-model` is equivalent to `v-bind:value` and `v-on:input` but if you look closer, in the listener function, the variable binded is set with the event property. What you do in your exemple isn't the same, in your listener you emit another event. Unless you catch this new event, your value will never be set.

Another thing is you can't modify a props, you should consider it like a read-only variable.

If you want to listen from the parent to the emitted event into the child component, you have to do something like this

```
<template>
  <el-select
    :value="selected"
    @input="dispatch"
    placeholder="Filter by short name"
    :filterable="true"
    :remote="true"
    :remote-method="filter"
    :loading="loading">
    <el-option
      v-for="item in clients"
      :key="item._id"
      :label="item.name"
      :value="item._id">
    </el-option>
  </el-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SelectClient',

  data() {
    return {
      selected: '',
      clients: [],
      loading: false,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    filter(query) {
      if (query !== '') {
        this.loading = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.loading = false
          this.clients = [{_id: '1', name: 'foo'}, {_id: '2', name: 'bar'}]
        }, 200)
      } else {
        this.clients = []
      }
    },

    dispatch (e) {
      this.$emit('input', e)
      this.selected = e
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

NB: a `v-model` + `watch` pattern will work too. The important thing is to `$emit` the input event, so the `v-model` in the parent will be updated.

And in your parent you can use this component like this: `<select-client v-model="clientId"/>`.

Tips: if you want to modify the same data in different place, you should have a single source of truth and prefer something like [vuex](http://vuex.vuejs.org/). Then your component will be like this

```
<template lang="html">
  <select
    v-model="clientId">
    <option
      disabled
      value="">Please select one</option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      clientId: ''
    }
  },

  watch: {
    clientId (newValue) {
      // Do something else here if you want then commit it
      // Of course, listen for the 'setClientId' mutation in your store
      this.$store.commit('setClientId', newValue)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then in your other components, you can listen to `$store.state.clientId` value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your code, it does not work. The console tells me `undefined selectedOptions`, I think `el-select` transform the raw event and therefore `event.target` is no longer existed. I'm very new to Frontend, so I could get it wrong :-(

Comment: Just a note: the"this.selected = e" in `dispatch` is also very important, and I believe `<el-select/>` is not well implemented because for `<el-input/>`, I don't have to set `this.value=e` explicitly

Comment: Thank you. I was looking exactly for the same solution...And I'm also using Element UI.

The el-select component is a bit confusing, because you don't know if actually is the el-select to fire the input event, or the el-option. In fact i think that they are both firing an event, but the best way is to watch the top-level only. 

I gaved a look at element-ui source code, there's also a good way of event propagantion, but the code can look a bit overcomplicated, there's also other stuff there. Maybe I will study that code a little more when I will have more time (aka.. never ;P)

Comment: Thank you a lot!, I was building a component similar like that and suddenly, I found out that  when you remove or set a value by code it was not refreshed in the component itself `filterForm.clientId = null`, I mean the variable `selected`. In order to fix that scenario I had to add a watch in the component itself such as the following : `watch:{ 'value':function(pnew, pold){ if(pnew==null) this.selected=null; } } `